# Expandable region in xml

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

In `C#` I can partition my code with `#region #endregion` keywords.

Is there any keywords in `xml` for this functionality?

I don't now whether its matters or not, I'm using `Visual Studio 2010`.

**EDIT :**

**For example:** I have distinct but corresponding tags like these above: I want to create a region for tool_planes and collapse them. Then create a region for tool_lines, etc.

```
        <RibbonSeparatablePopupMenu key="tool_Plane1" preferred-tool-size="Large" Type="Classic">
            <RibbonGallery key="tool_Plane_Gallery1"    >
                <RibbonGalleryCategory key="tool_Plane_Category1">
                    <RibbonGalleryCategoryItem  key="tool_Plane_3PointPlane" />
                    ...
                </RibbonGalleryCategory>
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonSeparatablePopupMenu>

        <RibbonSeparatablePopupMenu key="tool_Plane2" preferred-tool-size="Large" Type="Classic">
            <RibbonGallery key="tool_Plane_Gallery2"    >
                <RibbonGalleryCategory key="tool_Plane_Category2">
                    <RibbonGalleryCategoryItem  key="tool_Plane_OrthogonalPlane" />
                    ...
                </RibbonGalleryCategory>
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonSeparatablePopupMenu>
```

I don't want to group them with separate xml tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XAML Regions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177) is a Visual Studio Extension that provides the ability to create regions in XML/XAML code.

[image: XAML Regions]

Usage:

```
<!-- Region (Any Text You Want) --> 
Your Code 
<!-- EndRegion -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to collapse the fluff, you can use the collapse toggle.  It's as useful as regions when dealing with a very large Xml file.

[image]